# How do you use gnuplot from xcode?

Tags: c, xcode, macos, terminal, gnuplot

I want to use gnuplot by calling it from xcode. I have it on the terminal and it works fine, I just don't know how to plot from C. I have MacOS Catalina.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to use C? If you can use C++ there is really handy wrapper called [gnuplot-iostream](https://github.com/dstahlke/gnuplot-iostream)